# Alternative for "tail -f" that follows filename

Tags: linux, logging, tail

I have some logs being generated using a timed rotating file logger. This logs to a file called `tool.log`, and at midnight, moves this to `tool.log.<date>` and starts a new `tool.log`.

I have a `tail -f tool.log` running on the machine to keep an eye on the logs, but at midnight, when `tool.log` is renamed to `tool.log.<date>`, `tail` continues to watch the renamed file.

What I'm hoping for is a tool that is similar to `tail`, but will continue to monitor the file named `tool.log`, rather than following the inode.

Does something like this exist? If not, I can write my own in Python for this purpose.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22698/how-to-do-a-tail-f-of-log-rotated-files

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Some implementations of `tail` have an option for this; here's the description from the man page for GNU tail:

> **`-F`**
> same as `--follow=name --retry`

> **`-f`**, **`--follow`**[`=`{*name*|*descriptor*}]
> output appended data as the file grows; `-f`, `--follow`, and `--follow=descriptor` are equivalent
>
> **`--retry`**
> keep trying to open a file even when it is or becomes inaccessible; useful when following by name, i.e., with `--follow=name`

As this option isn't specified by POSIX, you can't depend on it everywhere.  Some known implementations:

- [**GNU**](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html) - has `-F` as described above
- [**Mac OS X**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tail.1.html), [**FreeBSD**](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tail&sektion=1) and [**NetBSD**](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?tail+1) - have a similar `-F` option with the same effect
- [**OpenBSD**](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tail.1) - `-f` is enough (if the file is replaced (i.e., the inode number changes), tail will reopen the file and continue)
- [**Solaris**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/tail-1.html) - no equivalent
- [**Busybox**](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/coreutils/tail.c) - `-F` is available in recent versions, but must be compiled with `ENABLE_FEATURE_FANCY_TAIL` (it's not compiled-in by default)

Answer (score 55):

Alternative is `tail -F` command.

The `-F` option implies `--follow=name` with `--retry` option, so tail is watching your file even if it has been deleted and created again.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Since you have asked for **alternative**:</sup>

The **`less`** utility could be an alternative for `tail -F`.

It will have to be run as follows: `less --follow-name filename.log` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

This will give you same results as `tail -F`.

Comment: Thanks. I was only after an alternative because I was unaware of tail -F. Always good to know options though.

Comment: I see two problematic things with `less +F --follow-name`: **1.** it fails if the file does not exist at the time `less` is started. **2.** `less` frequently crashes when the content of the file is replaced.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative would be to use the `watch` command, which will repeat any command every n seconds, every 2 seconds in this example:

```
watch -n2 "tail tool.log"
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit the command when you're finished viewing the log.

Comment: This seems like it would create a lot of duplicate messages if the log scrolled slower than the refresh timer, and would miss some messages if it scrolled faster.

Comment: Watch takes over the whole screen, so it wouldn't duplicate messages, but it would remove the ability to scroll back.

Answer (score 4):

[lnav](http://lnav.org/) is another fantastic tool that follows the filename.

You can also point it to a directory and it will tail all the files in that directory, in addition to all kinds of other neat features.

Comment: I've found it doesn't handle truncated and/or renamed rotated logs (I'm not sure which is upsetting it in my particular case) so the logs appear to stop at midnight unless I restart lnav. Am I missing some obvious switch or technique for it I wonder as this seems like something it should take in its stride?

Comment: It depends on how the file is truncated. If you pass the `-r` flag to lnav it will reload the filename (and load any previously rotated out logs)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `multitail` will handle your specific case, but I bet it does.  multitail does pretty much everything you could want `tail` to do.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiTail

Comment: Yes it will -- `multitail -f <name1> -f <name2> -f <name3> ...`. This example shows following several files simultaneously, which will be shown in separate windows.